# Tag synonym request: [replace] and [search-and-replace]

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

The tags [replace](/questions/tagged/replace) and [search-and-replace](/questions/tagged/search-and-replace) appear to be synonyms. The [replace](/questions/tagged/replace) tag has a (short) wiki entry while [search-and-replace](/questions/tagged/search-and-replace) does not, and there are roughly six times as many questions tagged [replace](/questions/tagged/replace), so even though I'd personally prefer [search-and-replace](/questions/tagged/search-and-replace) to be the base tag, it appears the community would prefer to use [replace](/questions/tagged/replace).

Comment: There's also the [tag:find-and-replace] tag which should be added into this somewhere.