# Retagging [find][replace] questions with [find-and-replace]

Tags: discussion, retag-request

Please retag [questions tagged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/find+replace) with [find](/questions/tagged/find)[replace](/questions/tagged/replace) (121 questions) with the
[find-and-replace](/questions/tagged/find-and-replace) tag (486 questions).

Comment: Related: [Tag synonym request: [replace\] and [search-and-replace\]](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/145993)

Comment: @animuson `[find-and-replace]` and `[search-and-replace]` should definitely be merged.

Comment: I agree, but they should also be merged with [tag:replace], since replacing text with some other text implies *finding* that text *to be replaced* first.

Comment: Find all [find] and [replace] tags and replace them. Wow, this does belong on meta.