# The unfortunate case of [replace]

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags

**[replace](/questions/tagged/replace)** <sub>7185</sub> already has a somewhat colourful history here on Meta, having aleady been mentioned in two tag merge requests {[1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/157758/223030), [2](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/145993/223030)}. It and its synonyms are being subjected to a set of far more terrifying problems, though. These can be identified merely by examining the **Related Tags** list:

- ## 12 <sub>216</sub> is [search](/questions/tagged/search), and #15 <sub>195</sub> is [find](/questions/tagged/find), suggesting that synonyms [find-and-replace](/questions/tagged/find-and-replace) and [search-and-replace](/questions/tagged/search-and-replace) are not being used as much as they should be.
- ## 5 <sub>750</sub> is [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery), and #20 <sub>135</sub> is [arrays](/questions/tagged/arrays), barely scratching the surface of the misuse of the tag (the wiki says it's for replacing substrings).
- ## 1 <sub>1899</sub> is [regex](/questions/tagged/regex), suggesting that it spends a lot of time as a meta-tag.

And isn't it ambiguous! It's been seen on string replacement questions, regex questions, collection item replacement questions, file copying questions ([this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18673266/1053021) bears [copy](/questions/tagged/copy), which is ringing alarm bells also), questions about which algorithm text editors use for find-and-replace ([kill with fire!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18631702/1053021)), and [whatever the heck is going on here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18719012/1053021) (why is that even tagged [replace](/questions/tagged/replace)?).

Something needs to be done. Given the extent of the misuse, it seems to be named in too generic a fashion, and I'd recommend burninating it. (I tend to recommend that a lot, though - take with a pinch of salt.)

---

*There are tags named [search-replace](/questions/tagged/search-replace) and [character-replacement](/questions/tagged/character-replacement) that may also need some attention.*

Comment: I second burnination. I would suggest also retagging, but that is _7,185 questions to retag_, so I don't think I am prepared to suggest that.

Answer (score 2):

I just went to a question and in the tags section typed "search"

"search-and-replace" did not show up in the set of auto-suggested tags. I had to type "search-" before it showed up.

I'm guessing that's why it isn't being used very often.

Oh... and I agree - it's ambiguous in meaning. Do we as-standard burninate ambiguous tags? If so - yay burninate!

Comment: It's also a synonym of replace, so it *can't* be used on new questions...

Comment: hmmm... and we can't make replace a synonym of search-and-replace because the subset goes the other way around. So... remove the synonym-link perhaps?

Comment: I've said this somewhere before, but "replace" in itself *implies* searching. You can't replace something without finding something *to replace* first.

Comment: @animuson In that case, the real problem is the number of questions tagged [[tag:search]] [[tag:replace]].

Comment: @animuson - I kind of disagree. In most contexts yes, but in the context of jquery et al, replace is an equivalent of gsub - you are doing string-replace, but it's not generally referred-to as "search and replace"