# What to do with the [circular] tag?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, retag-request, burninate-request

For the [circular](/questions/tagged/circular) tag it says:

> A logical fallacy in which the developer begins with what he is trying to end up with, like class A extends B, class B extends A.

The above looks related to, but rather distinct from, [circular-dependency](/questions/tagged/circular-dependency). And I can't imagine a question being asked where the above description would be applicable.

Even if there can be such questions, most of the questions currently tagged with [circular](/questions/tagged/circular) are either about [circular-dependency](/questions/tagged/circular-dependency), [circular-buffer](/questions/tagged/circular-buffer), [circular-list](/questions/tagged/circular-list) or pretty much anything which **isn't** about what it says in the description.

There are questions that uses [circular](/questions/tagged/circular) as meaning, well, circular (as in "round"), although not many.

What's the best course of action here?

- Burninate it, as the tag is often used to mean opposing things.
- Change it to mean "round".
- Make it a synonym of another tag, possibly [circular-dependency](/questions/tagged/circular-dependency).

Comment: I don't know what you're talking about. This looks like a very well-rounded tag...

Comment: @animuson +1 for the pun (just to clarify for those that aren't quite on the ball).

Comment: I just made edit suggestions to retag the 11 questions tagged both [tag:circular] and [tag:dependencies] with [tag:circular-dependency].

Comment: I've taken care of [tag:circular]+[tag:reference] => [tag:circular-reference].  146 left.

Comment: Most of the circular-dependency, circular-reference, circular-buffer and circular-list questions are taken care of, still 90 to go, many of these mean 'round', so I suppose we should change the description to that.