# If you create a tag, you shouldn't get reputation by adding it to questions

Tags: feature-request, tags, reputation, suggested-edits, tag-creation

There is a mass edit dump into the Suggested Edit review queue in Music.SE, by me. I'm suggesting several edits adding [tritone](/questions/tagged/tritone), a tag that I created, to all tritone-related questions I can find. I don't think I should be getting rep from edits doing only that, since anyone with tag-creation rep can create a tag and edit it into many relevant questions, and might even boost themselves up all the way to editing rep.

My proposed feature: if anyone creates a tag, they won't get rep from suggested edits that add only that tag (and possibly remove one other tag if there are five tags), without doing anything else.

P.S. I'm editing those questions because they are all tritone-related, not for the rep.

P.P.S. Invisible things shouldn't count. I'm pretty sure there's a policy to reject edits that only add or remove invisible things, but such an edit combined with an edit adding your tag shouldn't award any rep.

P.P.P.S. [Dom♦ removed the [tag:tritone] tag](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3940/what-just-happened-to-the-tritone-tag) from all questions which had it, and since he's a mod, I'm not going to recreate that tag.

Comment: I'm only seeing two suggested edits so far, that's not a mass edit dump in my book :) - As with any edits, try to limit them - on most reasonably active sites, three per day is not really disruptive, but more may be.

Comment: @Glorfindel I have suggested such [tag:tritone] edits eleven times so far.

Comment: I'm thinking it should be retroactive.

Comment: I entered the review queue on [music.se] but somehow those didn't show to me ...

Comment: Not to mention I have done lots of edits correcting sharp and flat symbols there, so probably about 95% of suggested edit traffic is from me nowadays...

Comment: @mathlander Is this enough of a _problem_ to justify modifying the network's software, adding a (perhaps computationally-expensive) exception to the reputation handling, and then recalculating _everybody's_ reputation according to the new rules? I've seen bad bulk tagging before, but I don't entirely understand the motives of people who do it.

Comment: Right, [I have a history](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3058/do-we-accept-edits-that-simply-update-the-characters-used-for-accidentals/3060#comment7937_3500) of correcting sharp and flat symbols there - actually I stopped doing that ...

Comment: @Glorfindel: You can see mathlander's suggested edits on [the Suggestions tab under "All actions" on their Music.SE profile's Activity tab](https://music.stackexchange.com/users/90057/mathlander?tab=activity&sort=suggestions). I think the other suggested edits have probably just already been handled.

Comment: Unrelated: the meta post on Music made me reconsider my decision on sharp and flat symbols.

Comment: @V2Blast yeah, I already visited that link and reviewed a couple more. I still don't know why those didn't appear in the regular queue - they're not like FA/FQ/LA items which are 'locked' for five minutes if another user visits them.

Comment: [The list](https://music.stackexchange.com/users/90057/mathlander?tab=activity&sort=revisions). You ought to fix *everything* else in those posts while you are at it. Grammar, removing forumness like *"Does anyone ...?"*, add missing space before "(", remove superfluous/meta content like *"My question is"*, remove unnecessary formatting, consider some answers as well because the question is bumped, etc.

Comment: If we do other fixing, then yes, we deserve the rep.

Comment: @mathlander As a greedy reputation hoarder (proof: see my mSE profile), I'd just add an HTML comment, or make some trivial change, to each of the questions I re-tagged.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 I edited the post.

Comment: See related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/197062/no-reputation-for-continued-tag-edits/197069#197069. I disagree with this post, since tag-only edits can still be valuable.

Comment: Personally, I'd rather a simple tag edit didn't even show as an edit at all, once you're past getting the 2 points needing review. I tend to only edit tags on brand new posts these days, to prevent bumping & I'd rather keep my name off the bottom of the question for something so trivial. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29394/it-should-be-possible-to-retag-a-question-without-bumping-it-to-the-front-page has been live for over a decade with no progress. Dupes are just flagged against it & closed.

Comment: @Tetsujin Unfortunately, there are abuses of tag edits, both historical and current, even by high-rep users, so such edits do need to bump questions in order for the edit/question to be seen and, effectively, reviewed by other users.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As a user of that site, I have noticed your retag edits — they aren't bad, but they could be  more thorough, and slightly less frequent.

Applying the appropriate tags is useful and should be encouraged.  The plus 2 rep is rather trivial, and when you get to 2000, you'll stop receiving rep from edits.  But when you retag, you should also take the time to find other appropriate edits on the question *& the answers* on that page (such as fixing typos) — do this and you'll deserve the extra reputation.

I went through a similar process that took months to add a new tag to 100-or-so questions.
I was sure to first ask on the local meta if the new tag was wanted by the community (see [New tag for repeats](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3880/new-tag-for-repeats)), and even asked a question here on the main meta site if there was a better method for adding new tags to old question. (Spoiler: *there isn't*, see [The system for adding a new tag to old questions is broken](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/379993/the-system-for-adding-a-new-tag-to-old-questions-is-broken))

On the relatively slow Music:P&T site, 2 or 3 retags per day is fine, but any more than this is a little problematic as it pushes other questions off of the active page — this is a slight concern, but the gain in reputation isn't.

Comment: "when you get to 2000" or when you get 500 rep from edits. There's a cap on reputation via suggested edits.

Answer (score 6):

### You should get the reputation for the approved, helpful suggested edit

Even if you've created the tag, I don't see a reason why you shouldn't get reputation for adding making helpful, successful, suggested edits which add the tag into appropriate questions. Creating the tag and editing it into questions is either helpful, or it's not. If it's actually helpful and you do the work, why wouldn't you get the reputation? Yes, there's the possibility of abuse, but such abuse is an exception, which is something that users should end up seeing and raising "in need of moderator intervention" flags explaining the issue. Moderators can then make the determination as to if the tag in those questions is actually useful and deal with the situation and user appropriately.

Your edits to questions to add the tag *should* fix everything that needs to be fixed in the question, because that's the courteous thing to do, resulting in the least impact on other users. You should also limit the number of questions edited in any particular period of time such that those edits don't dominate the site's home page, question activity page, or any tag's activity page (other than the one you're creating). What volume of edits that means will greatly depend on the site and tags. For example, if the tags in the questions are high volume tag, then it could be that it only takes a few minutes for things to roll off the activity page. For very low volume tags it could take months (literally).

If adding the tag to questions is going to involve a lot of questions (where "lot" is defined by your site; on SO it's 50), then you should create a question on your site's meta to A) discuss if the tag's useful, and B) coordinate the editing work with others. Given that a suggested edit *actually* takes work from multiple people (one to edit and then a few to review and approve the edit), it's better to have any significant volume of edits performed by users with full edit privileges who don't need to submit suggested edits.

Comment: There's a problem: Soon enough, people might create other interval-related tags, like [tag:perfect-fifth], and start editing them into questions. Getting rid of the rep for such edits would probably provide motivation to not flood the homepage by adding interval tags.

Comment: @mathlander I disagree. That sounds like a situation where a question should be created on the site's meta that discusses the general concept and enumerates all of the tags which might be desired. You can then get buy-in from the community that such tags are helpful and wanted. You and the community can then work through editing them into questions.